# Trying to create a usergroup in Jira Cloud with REST API

Tags: rest, api, cloud, jira

I have an upcoming tool migration where I can import assignees but not inactive ones - and there is no user group by default with only active users.

So I've exported all jira users and filtered based on active - so I have a nice list of all their usernames/emails. Now I want to use the REST API to create a usergroup from the list and add each user.

From the API documentation, it's pretty straightforward:

`curl --request POST \
  --url '/rest/api/3/group/user' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "accountId": "384093:32b4d9w0-f6a5-3535-11a3-9c8c88d10192"
}'`

However, I'm not about to type in one by one the accountIds. How can I specify an excel list or how else can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought - Just made a bash script where accountId's is the variable to cycle through the addresses.